# Simple differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following exercise where you got 2 paintings, which are made from an special paint made up from Ra-226 and Pb-210. The Ra-226 desintegrates into Pb-210 and then the Pb-206.
The Ra-226 has a half-life of 1600 years and the Pb-210 has a half-life of 22 years.

The following table shows the amount of Ra-226 and Pb-210 found in the paintings:

|  | Ra-226 | Pb-210 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Painting A | 2000 | 283 |
| Painting B | 3500 | 50 |

It is also known that the initial amount of Pb-210 was bigger than 11/789 X times the initial amount of Ra-226.

So far, I have done the following:

I obtained the decay constants of the elements $ \lambda_1 = \ln 2 /1600 = 4.33*10^{-4}$ for the Ra-226 and $ \lambda_2 = \ln 2 /22= 3.15*10^{-2}$ for the Pb-210.

then I the equations: (where z is the amount of Ra-226 and y is the amount of Pb-210).
$$\left\{
\frac{dz}{dt} = -4.33*10^{-4}z \atop
\frac{dy}{dt} = 4.33*10^{-4}z + 3.15*10^{-2}y
\right.$$

I solved the equations so I got:
$$\left(
z \atop
y
\right) =
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
\frac{811*\ln(2)}{17600} & 0\\
\frac{-\ln(2)}{1600} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
e^\frac{-\ln(2)t}{1600} & 0\\
0 & e^\frac{\ln(2)t}{22}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
k_1 \atop
k_2
\right)
$$

I am stucked here, I thought of setting t=0 and try to find out the values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ and use the condition that $y(0) > \frac{11}{789}z(0)$.
So I did something like this:

$$\left(
z(0) \atop
y(0)
\right) =
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
\frac{811*\ln(2)}{17600} & 0\\
\frac{-\ln(2)}{1600} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
k_1 \atop
k_2
\right)
$$
I obtained bounded values of $k_1=31.3087*z(0)$ and $k_2=0.01356*z(0)+\frac{11}{789}*z(0)$
And now I solve the ecuations giving the corresponding values to $z$ and $y$:
$$\left(
2000 \atop
283
\right) =
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
\frac{811*\ln(2)}{17600} & 0\\
\frac{-\ln(2)}{1600} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
e^\frac{-\ln(2)t}{1600} & 0\\
0 & e^\frac{\ln(2)t}{22}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
31.3087*z(0) \atop
0.0275*z(0)
\right)
$$
and
$$\left(
3500\atop
50
\right) =
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
\frac{811*\ln(2)}{17600} & 0\\
\frac{-\ln(2)}{1600} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(  
\begin{matrix}
e^\frac{-\ln(2)t}{1600} & 0\\
0 & e^\frac{\ln(2)t}{22}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
31.3087*z(0) \atop
0.0275*z(0)
\right)
$$

but I get some weird times:
for the painting A its 54 years which is fine, but for the paining B its 0.395 years.

I can't figure out the error.

Comment: FYI use `\ln` instead of `ln` to typeset $\ln$ in MathJax.

Comment: I think you might have switched $y$ and $z$ a couple times. You have $z(0)$ twice in the matrix and earlier, you have $\frac{dz}{dt}$ twice.

Comment: Sorry, its true I fixed the text